# How to add CSS to page to the bottom of the <head> custom chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension and I'd like to apply CSS to the bottom of the `<head>` in the html.

Here's my code

```
"content_scripts" : [ {
  "matches": ["*://*.roblox.com/*"],
  "js": ["inject.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start",
  "css": [ "obc.css" ]
} ]
```

Whenever I run this, it doesn't put the CSS at the bottom of the head.
Any ideas to move the CSS?

Comment: I wonder, why do you need this to explicitly be a `<head>` sub-entry? Your CSS will apply regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,add this to mainfest file:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*://*.roblox.com/*"],
  "js": ["inject.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "obc.css"
],
```

And, in inject.js:

```
var linkElem = document.createElement('link'),
cssSrc = chrome.extension.getURL('inject.css'),
head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

// Normal html will only have one head element, so, use [0] is ok, right?

linkElem.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
linkElem.setAttribute('href', cssSrc);

head.appendChild(linkElem);
```

**At the end, Please check** you have change 'document_start' to 'document_end', or you will get UNDEFINED head element

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH MAN! I was trying this for 2 hours now and you're my solution.

Comment: @RoweRowe Read and understand this >> https://developer.chrome.com/extensions , I think it's best document for Chrome Extension develop

Comment: Is that good? Or do I need something else? And alright I will read up on it, thanks again.

Comment: @RoweRowe Yeah, Thank you too. And i have edit last comment, linked to Google offical document, may you want bookmark it.